# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_agent' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

I my MySQL database I have a column called `user_agent`. I'm filling this via PHP. Sometimes this may be empty.

I'm getting the following error message:

> [12-Feb-2018 08:09:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1048 Column 'user_agent' cannot be null' in
>   /home/user_name/public_html/folder/index.php:112

I read I should enable NULL.

Why can't this filed simply be empty? Empty string is a string, too, isn't it?

EDIT:

This is my PHP code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO log (ip, user_agent) VALUES (:ip, :user_agent)");
$statement->execute(array(':ip' => $ip, ':user_agent' => $user_agent));
```

Seems like some visitors don't have a user_agent.

This is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_agent` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Yes, an empty string is still a `string`. However, it looks more or less like the variable your referencing is not set. You can either define the variable by `default` as an empty string or allow the column to be `NULL`

Comment: `the variable your referencing is not set`; You mean, not set in PHP?

Comment: Paste your `create table` statement. Only then one would be able to tell exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: @David: Correctly. Can you provide more details about your query?

Comment: @fab I updated my first post with PHP code and create table statement.

Comment: @YusufHassan I did so now.

Comment: Try this: `$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?: '';` (or if you using PHP7 `$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? '';`

Comment: Where's your column `test`?

Comment: In addition, you log table is missing the `user_agent` column.

Comment: @kerbholz `test` is `user_agent`

Comment: @fab Sorry, you're right, added it.

Comment: Try the provided example or allow the column `user_agent` to be `NULL`. Therefore, delete the word `NOT` in your create statement.

Comment: You have declared the field to be `NOT NULL`, it'll always expect a value. Not putting anything in the field will be treated as `NULL`. You shouldn't interpret that as `still being a string.`

Answer (score 0):

You should set a value to your `id` as it is not auto_incrementable. Or you can also modify the id to be auto_incrementable with :

```
ALTER TABLE `log` MODIFY COLUMN `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

If some visitors don't have user agent you can redefine the user_agent column to be nullable.

```
ALTER TABLE `log` MODIFY COLUMN `user_agent` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL;
```

Else you won't be able to log their actions.
After running these commands the insert should work.

Answer (score 0):

In create statement this filed is like

```
 `user_agent` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,
```